# What is the other word that can be instead of sequel?

Tags: word-request

> *The philosophy sets an awfully high bar for a Toy Story **sequel** - the first three have grossed more than US$ 1.3 billion worldwide.*

What is another word that can be instead of ***sequel***? Next episode?

Comment: Asking for another word for a specific word is basically asking for a definition of the word, which is off topic. ELL is not a dictionary, and it is not a thesauras. You are expected to do some of your own research before asking a question. See the help page. Most dictionaries do give synonyms. Which dictionaries did you consult and what word or words caused you difficulties?

Answer (score 2):

'Sequel' is often used for the next part of movie/animation etc. However you can also use words like [follow up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/follow%20up) and [continuation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/continuation).

For example, a *continuation* of xyz story; or a *follow up* movie.